# increment variable in awk based on two columns

Tags: linux, shell, variables, awk, count

I am writing an `awk` script that parses a CSV file, compares one column containing date, and another column containing activity type, and then prints the count of a particular activity.

The code I have written is:

```
NOW=$(date --date="5 days ago" +"%Y%m%d")
awk -F "," -v mydate=$NOW '{
    var_1=1;
    var_2=1;} {
    if ( substr($8,2,8) == mydate ) {
                if ( $6 == 1001 ) {
                    var_1++;
                }
                else if ( $6 == 1003 ) {
                    var_2++;
                }
    }
    print var_1 var_2
}' *.csv
```

The output I get is

```
11
11
11
11
11
11
```

I believe the issue is something to do with the way I have defined `var_1` and `var_2`; they are reinitialized or something.

Also I want to only print the final value of `var_1` and `var_2`; at the moment, it gets printed with every iteration of `awk`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two blocks that are executed on each line of data:

1. `{ var_1=1; var_2=1; }` which sets the variables to 1 on each pass.
2. `{
   if ( substr($8,2,8) == mydate ) {
               if ( $6 == 1001 ) {
                   var_1++;
               }
               else if ( $6 == 1003 ) {
                   var_2++;
               }
   }
   print var_1 var_2
   }` which prints the values of `var_1` and `var_2` as concatenated strings (hence no space between the 1 and 1).

It appears that either the `substr()` condition or the `$6` condition is not being matched, ever.

You probably wanted `BEGIN` before the first block, but why you'd start at 1 rather than 0 is not obvious.  If you started the counts at 0, you wouldn't need a BEGIN block.  You should probably use `print var_1, var_2` to separate the two values.

As for why the matches aren't matching, there's no way to say without any sample data to work on, but you could debug by printing out `$8` and `$6` for each line (and `mydate`, too; and maybe `substr($8,2,8)`), so you can see what is happening.

If you only want the values to print at the end, then (once you've debugged what's happening during the main action), you can place the `print` in an END block:

```
END { print var_1, var_2 }
```

Comment: thanks, BEGIN, END is what i was looking for. conditions are matching fine.